# C++ Global object definition depending on link order

Tags: c++, linker, global-variables

Given main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A a;

int main() {
}
```

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_HDR
#define A_HDR

class A {
 public:
  A();  
};

#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

A::A() {
  std::cout << "A ctor\n";
}
```

I create the relocatable object files `main.o` and `A.o` with `g++ -c`. Then:

```
> g++ main.o A.o
> ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> g++ A.o main.o
>./a.out
A ctor
```

Why the difference?
If I move the definition of `a` from the global namespace into the scope of `main` it prints out `A ctor` as I expect.

```
> g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Segmentation Fault when using cout in static variable initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318693/c-segmentation-fault-when-using-cout-in-static-variable-initialization)

Comment: Yes, putting the #include <iostream> in the common hdr file fixed the problem, as it did there. So by listing the relocatable object file that includes the std:;cout definition (A.o) first, also fixed the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Due to global objects in C++ creates in an undefined order
In the first case: object "a" (which in global space) creates earlier that std::cout and we have failed on access to std::cout at "A::A()".

Comment: Yes. Either by putting A.o (which includes <iostream> so defining std::cout) first on the cmd line, or by including <iostream> in main.cpp as well (say through A.h), creates std::cout before object "a" creates.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), under the *Non-local variables*, *Dynamic initialization* section. cout is initialized in one translation unit, A.cpp, while a is initialized in another, main.cpp. The order within a single translation unit is sequenced as the order that the definitions appear, but between translation units is indeterminate as per section 3) there, *Ordered dynamic initialization*.